# Select rows from dataframe by hour

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataset with financial assets. Asset_id means one asset at a given timestamp. My dataframe has a time step per second, but I need to select each Asset_id for each hour in 'Date'. I tried ways with pd.mask() and iteration but i have too many rows

```
    timestamp  Asset_ID  Count       Open      High       Low      Close    Date
0  1514764860         2   40.0   2376.580   2399.50   2357.14   2374.590   2018-01-01 00:01:00
1  1514764860         0    5.0      8.530      8.53      8.53    8.530     2018-01-01 00:01:00
2  1514764860         1  229.0  13835.194  14013.80  13666.11  13850.176   2018-01-01 01:01:00
```

```
`     Asset_ID  Count      Open    High     Low      Close    Date
0           2   48.0   2876.580   199.50   2357.14   274.590    2018-01-01 01:01:00
1           0    5.0      8.530      4.5      8.53    8.530     2018-01-01 01:01:00
2           1  29.0  137435.194  14043.80  13666.11  13850.176  2018-01-01 01:01:00
3           1   50.0   9876.580   299.50   244357.14   274.590  2018-01-01 02:01:00`
```

Comment: what is the actual question ?https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df_train.between_time("00:01","12:01")
```